# Grammar ambiguity: why? (problem is: "(a)" vs "(a-z)")

Tags: parsing, haskell, grammar, happy

So I am trying to implement a pretty simple grammar for one-line statements:

```
# Grammar

   c         : Character c        [a-z0-9-]
  (v)        : Vowel              (= [a,e,u,i,o])
  (c)        : Consonant
  (?)        : Any character (incl. number)
  (l)        : Any alpha char     (= [a-z])
  (n)        : Any integer        (= [0-9])
  (c1-c2)    : Range from char c1 to char c2
  (c1,c2,c3) : List including chars c1, c2 and c3

  Examples:
  h(v)(c)no(l)(l)jj-k(n)
  h(v)(c)no(l)(l)(a)(a)(n)
  h(e-g)allo
  h(e,f,g)allo
  h(x,y,z)uul
  h(x,y,z)(x,y,z)(x,y,z)(x,y,z)uul
```

I am using the Happy parser generator (http://www.haskell.org/happy/) but for some reason there seems to be some ambiguity problem.

The error message is: "shift/reduce conflicts:  1"

I think the ambiguity is with these two lines:

```
  | lBracket char rBracket              { (\c -> case c of
                                                 'v' -> TVowel
                                                 'c' -> TConsonant
                                                 'l' -> TLetter
                                                 'n' -> TNumber) $2 }
  | lBracket char hyphen char rBracket  { TRange $2 $4              }
```

*An example case is: "(a)" vs "(a-z)"*

The lexer would give the following for the two cases:

```
(a)   : [CLBracket, CChar 'a', CRBracket]
(a-z) : [CLBracket, CChar 'a', CHyphen, CChar 'z', CRBracket]
```

**What I don't understand is how this can be ambiguous with an LL[2] parser.**

In case it helps here is the entire Happy grammar definition:

```
{

module XHappyParser where

import Data.Char
import Prelude   hiding (lex)
import XLexer
import XString

}

%name parse
%tokentype { Character  }
%error     { parseError }

%token
    lBracket                  { CLBracket   }
    rBracket                  { CRBracket   }
    hyphen                    { CHyphen     }
    question                  { CQuestion   }
    comma                     { CComma      }
    char                      { CChar $$    }

%%

xstring : tokens                            { XString (reverse $1)       }

tokens : token                              { [$1]                       }
       | tokens token                       { $2 : $1                    }

token : char                                { TLiteral $1                }
      | hyphen                              { TLiteral '-'               }
      | lBracket char rBracket              { (\c -> case c of
                                                     'v' -> TVowel
                                                     'c' -> TConsonant
                                                     'l' -> TLetter
                                                     'n' -> TNumber) $2 }
      | lBracket question rBracket          { TAny                      }
      | lBracket char hyphen char rBracket  { TRange $2 $4              }
      | lBracket listitems rBracket         { TList $2                  }

listitems : char                            { [$1]                      }
          | listitems comma char            { $1 ++ [$3]                }

{

parseError :: [Character] -> a
parseError _ = error "parse error"

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the ambiguity:

```
token : [...]
      | lBracket char rBracket
      | [...] 
      | lBracket listitems rBracket

listitems : char
          | [...]
```

Your parser could accept `(v)` as both `TString [TVowel]` and `TString [TList ['v']]`, not to mention the missing characters in that `case` expression.

One possible way of solving it would be to modify your grammar so lists are at least two items, or have some different notation for vowels, consonants, etc.

Comment: Thanks... that solved the problem (lists with one item are useless in this case anyway, so I removed them). But what do you mean with the case statement?

Comment: @o1iver: Only that you probably want to add a default case to it to handle single characters that are not one of `v, c, ?, l, n` to signal a more meaningful error than "Non-exhaustive patterns in case expression".

Comment: yes I did have that before, but I wasn't sure. I think I will just throw an error if that happens... Although I guess I will have to have a better look at the Happy docs concerning error handling in general! Thanks again...

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be:

```
| lBracket char rBracket
...
| lBracket listitems rBracket
```

or in cleaner syntax:

```
(c)
```

Can be a TVowel, TConsonant, TLetter, TNumber (as you know) or a singleton TList.

As the happy manual says, shift reduce usually isn't an issue.  You can us precedence to force behavior/remove the warning if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking in the wrong place. The problem really seems to be the singleton list vs the special chars ("(v)", "(n)", etc...). Thank you!